# Django. Выпадающий список в форме

Tags: django

Имеется модель Post с полем "category". В модели есть несколько объектов с разными значениями этого поля ('url', 'file', 'video'). Как при создании объекта через форму сделать выпадающий список для этого поля, чтобы можно было либо выбрать одно значение из существующих (отсеив дубликаты), либо вписать новое значение? Пробую сделать через

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Post.objects.values('category'))
```

но в выпадающем списке вываливается всё в виде словарей:

```
{'category':'url'}
{'category':'file'}
{'category':'video'}
```

По сути надо, избавиться от ключей, оставив только значения. Ну и плюс нужно добавить возможность вместо только выбора существующего вписать/создать новую категорию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список уникальных значений можно получить так:

```
Post.objects.order_by().values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
```

Но, если нужно уметь редактировать эти категории, то лучше сделать отдельную модель `Category` и привязать её к `Post` как ForeignKey

Comment: То, что надо. Большое спасибо.